# Having an issue with Unity(C#) my score counter is also adding +1 when i hit a different object (my +1HP object)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

This script is on the player, to destroy coins when touched by him.

```cs
private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
{
    if(other.gameObject.CompareTag("Coins"))
    {
        AudioSource.PlayClipAtPoint(coinSound, transform.position);
        Destroy(other.gameObject);
    }
}
```

This script is for the HP up object, that adds +1hp when touched by the player. `ScoreManager` - Changes the written score so the player can see it updated.

```cs
public class ScoreManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    public static ScoreManager instance;
    int score = -1;
    public Text text;
    
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        if(instance == null)
        {
            instance = this;
        }
    }
    
    // Ao tocar numa moeda, é acrescentado o valor "x" ao Score, o valor x pode ser mudado manualmente no Unity, podendo utilizar o mesmo script para moedas de diferente valor;
    public void ChangeScore(int coinValue)
    {
        score = score + coinValue;
        text.text = "x" + score.ToString();
    }
}
```

CoinSystem - Adds +1 when to the score when player touches a coin.

```cs
public class CoinSystem : MonoBehaviour
{
    public int coinValue = 1;
    // Atualiza o Score no canvas
    private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
    {
        if(other.gameObject.CompareTag("Player"));
        {
            ScoreManager.instance.ChangeScore(coinValue);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please edit your question to include a [mcve] as text.

Comment: @chriptus13 thanks for the edit but the next time please pay lore attention! OP had a **typo** `;` after the last `if` statement which was the cause for the issue .. your edit removed that typo and thereby obfuscated the actual issue for everyone else

Comment: @derHugo noticed that afterwards...

Answer (score 2):

I think that at least a part of your problem is that you have a semicolon ( ; ) right after your if statement in your `CoinSystem` class.

I recommend paying attention to Visual Studio's warnings. It is warning you about the possible mistaken empty statement, as seen by the green squiggly line.

Answer (score 0):

```
private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D Object1, Collider2D Object2){
    if(Object1.gameObject.CompareTag("Player") && Object2.GameObject.CompareTag("Coin")){
         ScoreManager.instance.ChangeScore(coinValue);
    }
}
```

Maybe try sending two objects to the void?

Comment: Hmm now nothing adds to the counter